# How do I increase the size of the default circle that surrounds the current location in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, geometry

Google Maps has a default blue circle that surrounds the dot of the current location. I wish to alter this dynamically i.e. make it bigger or smaller. How can I do this? Is there a built in method to manipulate this or do I have to use an overlay or something?

Circle on Google Maps:

[image]

Comment: That default blue circle represents the uncertainty of the position. Modifying it would most likely confuse users used to the google maps app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the size of the circle in Google Maps, for the simple reason that its size is very important.

The blue circle covers the area in which you have been placed. Location technologies are not precise, and the circle is to say that "We know you're somewhere in here, but not sure exactly where in there".

If you were allowed to change the size of the circle, it would defeat the purpose of the circle.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification. I did not know this =) I was hoping to use that circle as a way to show the boundaries of the nearby locations within a 25 mile radius. But I can skip this minor feature if this is the case

Comment: @JohnathanAu You can always draw your own circles on the map if you control the View.

Comment: Yes, I've thought about that but due to time constraints and that this is just a little thing I wanted to add to my app it doesn't matter at all :P